# Partition linked list around a value x : Cracking the coding Interview book

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

I am trying to solve an interview question such that the given linked list needs to be partition around a value say 'x'. I gave an attempt to it but not getting the desired result.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None

def Partition(head, x):
    x_node = Node(x)
    x_node.next = head
    current = head
    last = x_node
    while current:
        if current.val < x_node.val:
            last = last.next
            temp_val = current.val
            current.val = last.val
            last.val = temp_val
        current = current.next
    temp_val = last.val
    last.val = x_node.val
    x_node.val = temp_val

Partition(head,3)

Input:           1->4->3->2->5->2
Actual Output:   1->2->3->4->5->3
Expected Output: 1->2->2->3->4->5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this actually supposed to sort, or just partition? Because I see no reason the expected output would put 3 before 4.

Comment: Also, this code is swapping around values, not nodes, which is probably violating the spirit of the exercise; in Python, sure, swapping single values and node references is equivalent cost, but the whole point of linked lists is that you can rearrange nodes without changing anything but the node links.

Comment: @ShahdowRanger partition. Also, can you elaborate your second comment with an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For [9,2,9,3,5,8,5,10,2,1] (which I magically convert to a ll behind the scenes), I'm getting 1,2,3,2,9,9,5,8,5,10 for value 5.

The question is to have all items less than the value to the left of all items greater than or equal to the value, where the value itself can appear anywhere in the right partition. Notice 9 is appearing before 5, which is as expected.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

def partition(node, val):
b_n = node
head = node
right = False
while node:
    if node.data < val:
        if node == head:
            node = node.next
        else:
            head = Node(node.data, head)
            b_n.next = node.next
    else:
        right = True
        if right:
            r_e = node
    b_n = node
    node = node.next
r_e.next = None
return head

ll5 = Linked_List()
ll5.build_from_list([9,2,9,3,5,8,5,10,2,1])
ll6.head = partition(ll5.head, 5)
ll6.iterate()
```

**.build_from_list(), and .iterate() are methods that I built into my Linked_List() class.**